# Working with real functions in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In general, mathematica always assumes the most general case, that is, if I set a function

```
a[s_]:={a1[s],a2[s],a3[s]}
```

and want to compute its norm `Norm[a[s]]`, for example, it will return:

```
Sqrt[Abs[a1[s]]^2 + Abs[a2[s]]^2 + Abs[a3[s]]^2]
```

However, if I know that all `ai[s]` are real, I can invoke:

```
Assuming[{a1[s], a2[s], a3[s]} \[Element] Reals, Simplify[Norm[a[s]]]]
```

which will return:

```
Sqrt[a1[s]^2 + a2[s]^2 + a3[s]^2]
```

Which is what I expect.

Problem happens when trying to, for example, derive `a[s]` and then (note the `D`):

```
Assuming[{a1[s], a2[s], a3[s]} \[Element] Reals, Simplify[Norm[D[a[s],s]]]]
```

Returns again a result involving absolute values - coming from the assumption that the numbers may be imaginary.

*What is the way to overcome this problem? I want to define a real-valued function, and work with it as such. That is, for instance, I want its derivatives to be real.*

Comment: The answer I chose is not the most general one, but first it solved my problem. Secondly, it taught me the moral "you should take care of your code". Thanks for all the other nice and helpful answers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a custom function instead, e.g.

```
vecNorm[vec_?VectorQ] := Sqrt[ vec.vec ]
```

Then

```
In[20]:= vecNorm[D[{a1[s], a2[s], a3[s]}, s]]

Out[20]= Sqrt[
Derivative[1][a1][s]^2 + Derivative[1][a2][s]^2 + 
 Derivative[1][a3][s]^2]
```

Answer (score 6):

**Warning:** I don't have much practical experience with this, so the examples below are not thoroughly tested (i.e. I don't know if too general assumptions can break anything I haven't thought of).

---

You can use `$Assumptions` to define permanent assumptions:

We could say that all of `a1[s], a2[s], a3[s]` are reals:

```
$Assumptions = {(a1[s] | a2[s] | a3[s]) \[Element] Reals}
```

But if you have e.g. `a1[x]` (not `a1[s]`), then it won't work.  So we can improve it a bit using patterns:

```
$Assumptions = {(a1[_] | a2[_] | a3[_]) \[Element] Reals}
```

Or just say that all values of `a[_]` are real:

```
$Assumptions = {a[_] \[Element] Reals}
```

Or even be bold and say that everything is real:

```
$Assumptions = {_ \[Element] Reals}
```

(I wonder what this breaks)

`AppendTo` is useful for adding to `$Assumptions` and keeping previous assumptions.

Just like `Assuming`, this will only work for functions like `Simplify` or `Integrate` that have an `Assumtpions` option.  `D` is not such a function.

---

Some functions like `Reduce`, `FindInstance`, etc. have an option to work only on the domain of Reals, Integers, etc., which assumes that all expressions and subexpressions they work with are real.

---

`ComplexExpand[]` and sometimes `FunctionExpand[]` may also be useful in similar situations (but not really here).  Examples: `ComplexExpand[Abs[z]^2, TargetFunctions -> {Sign}]` and `FunctionExpand[Abs'[x], Assumptions -> {x \[Element] Reals}]`.

---

**Generally**, as far as I know, there is no *mathematical* way to tell Mathematica that a variable is real.  It is only possible to do this in a formal way, using patterns, and only for certain functions that have the `Assumptions` option.  By "formal" I mean that if you tell it that `a[x]` is real, it will not know automatically that `a'[x]` is also real.

Comment: "...there is no mathematical way to tell Mathematica that a variable is real..." IMO, this has been (and continues to be) a major point of frustration/confusion for me. One can assign the Attribute 'Constant' to a Symbol and info on Dt, for example, makes it seem like setting such an Attribute is a great way to inform Mathematica of your mathematical intent. I *really* wish there were Attributes allowing you to, when desirable, specify Real, PositiveReal, NonNegativeReal, NegativeReal, etc; perhaps even NonConstant (thinking of model building). Assumptions/simplification can be clunky.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ComplexExpand` in this case albeit with a workaround. For example

```
ComplexExpand[Norm[a'[s], t]] /. t -> 2
```

returns

```
Sqrt[Derivative[1][a1][s]^2 + Derivative[1][a2][s]^2 + Derivative[1][a3][s]^2]
```

Note that doing something like `ComplexExpand[Norm[a'[s], 2]]` (or indeed `ComplexExpand[Norm[a'[s], p]]` where `p` is a rational number) doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: That's weird.  You can also use `TargetFunctions -> {Sign}` by which I mean "don't use `Abs`" and not "use `Sign`".  Then no need for `Norm[..., 2]`.

Answer (score 2):

For older Mathematica versions there used to be an add-on package `RealOnly` that put Mathematica in a reals-only mode. There is a version available in later versions and [online](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6771/) with minimal compatibility upgrades. It reduces many situations to a real-only solution, but doesn't work for your `Norm` case:

[image]